# How can I get my battery level to display in the notification area (system tray)?

Tags: notification-area, awesome

I'm trying to use the Awesome window manager with GNOME, i.e. running `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` on login, and it works great for the most part, except for the fact that the notification area/systray is missing a battery indicator. There's the Network Manager applet (nm-applet), a keyboard icon for switching keyboard layouts, but no battery icon as I would've hoped. I thought the command would be something like gnome-power-manager,

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 12.10, but I had this same issue with 12.04 and earlier.

Comment: 13.10 has a similar issue. You can run gnome-settings-daemon at awesome start and nm-applet runs to give the network icon. However, the indicators installed through indicator-power, etc, don't seem to have simple executables that can be run any more.

Answer (score 2):

I use switched to using awesome a few weeks ago and quickly discovered the lack of icons. I hunted down `nm-applet` via `ps` but I see no such process for the battery. What I did find was [`acpitool`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/acpitool) which can query battery levels.

[image: screenshot]

I always meant to get around to writing a vicious icon for it, shouldn't be too hard. I just don't know lua.

Comment: There are a couple of different widgets (like in vicious) for showing battery levels, but I was hoping to find the GNOME applet. Since I'm already running GNOME in awesome, I figured I might as well. Also, GNOME's battery indicator tells you how much time you have left, and Vicious's doesn't.

Comment: "Already running GNOME in awesome" This line confuses me a bit. GNOME is a desktop environment, awesome is a window manager, if anything it would be "awesome in GNOME" (using GNOME to refer to the desktop environment excluding the default window manager).

Comment: You have a point there, but as I understand it, you can run a window manager on its own (i.e. without all the bells and whistles of a desktop environment) but it's not as easy to run a desktop environment without a WM. So for me, I launch awesome, then launch gnome-session, so it seems like I'm running gnome on top of awesome, instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple one after encountering the same problem.

You can check out all the details here:
http://www.everythingisvoid.com/linux/simple-battery-status-indicator-awesome-window-manager